# Created date of onenote page is not converted to local date by microsoft graph api

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

I am a little confused about the created date meta when creating onenote page by microsoft graph api. According to the [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn575442.aspx#bkmk_onsvc_creation), the date has to be a ISO 8601 standard time stamp, I first copied the date (`2013-06-11T06:30:00-08:00`) in the example to my code, and my onenote shows the creation date is `Tuesday, June 11, 2013 6:30 AM`, which is not what I expected, because the timezone of my city is `+8:00`, the date should be `Tuesday, June 11, 2013 22:30 PM`.

I tried to change date to `2013-06-11T06:30:00-10:00`, but my onenote still shows `Tuesday, June 11, 2013 6:30 AM`, it seems the timezone offset doesn't work.

The doc also mentions that we can use a timezone offset without date and time, so I tried `+00:00`, but it's also not converted to local date. At last, I tried `+08:00`, and it works fine.

Is the timezone offset ignored by graph api? Can I use an utc date in server side or do I have to get timezone in client side first?

Here is my function to create a page:

```
def create_page(section_id):
    page = request.json
    created_at = '2013-06-11T06:30:00-08:00'
    content = '''
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>{0}</title>
                <meta name="created" content="{1}" />
            </head>
            <body>
                {2}
            </body>
        </html>
    '''.format(page['title'], created_at, MARKDOWN_FILE_OBJECT_HTML)
    files = {
        'Presentation': ('', io.StringIO(content), 'text/html'),
        'markdown': ('markdown.md', io.StringIO(''), 'text/markdown')
    }

    oauth_client = oauth.microsoft_graph
    response = oauth_client.post(
        'me/onenote/sections/{0}/pages'.format(section_id), files=files).json()

    return jsonify(response)
```

And the request body:

```
--0971a31c3b8a4c79985d91774720e44b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Presentation"; filename=""
Content-Type: text/html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Untitled Page</title>
            <meta name="created" content="2013-06-11T06:30:00-08:00" /> 
        </head>
        <body>
            <object data-id="markdown-file" data-attachment="markdown.md" data="name:markdown" type="text/markdown" />
        </body>
    </html>
--0971a31c3b8a4c79985d91774720e44b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="markdown"; filename="markdown.md"
Content-Type: text/markdown
--0971a31c3b8a4c79985d91774720e44b--
```

Comment: Can you provide the actual payload you're providing in the `POST` to `/pages`?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I've updated my question, please check it again, thanks.

Comment: It isn't clear for the code (TBF it may just be that my python is a bit rusty) but are you setting the `content-type` to `multipart/form-data; boundary=0971a31c3b8a4c79985d91774720e44b`?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I didn't set the `content-type`, but the request library sets it for me. And here is the request header: `{'User-Agent': 'Authlib/0.7 (+https://authlib.org/)', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Length': '693', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=d2d283660cf9470485e8a1931006ba11', 'Authorization': 'Bearer token'}`. I ran the app again, so the boundary is different.